# Is this function a bijection?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

$f: \Bbb N \to P(\Bbb N)$ be given by $f(n) = \{n+1,n+2,n+3,\ldots\}.$

From general intuition and reasoning I think the function is not injective here is my work.

If $n = 1$
$f(1) = \{2,3,4,5,\ldots\}$


If $n = 2$ 
$f(2) = \{3,4,5,\ldots\}$

Since, $f(2)$ is a subset of $f(1)$ the function is not injective.

Comment: Hint:  Write out the exact definition of "injective".

Comment: I edited your question's title for grammar and changed $N$ to be the natural numbers; please check I didn't change what you meant to write.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $f(2) \subseteq f(1)$ does not show the function is not injective.

A function is injective if for $n,m \in \Bbb N$ you have $n\neq m \implies f(n) \neq f(m)$, so to show a function is not injective you would have to find two different numbers that have *the same* image under $f$ (you have one containment, not equality).

The function in this exercise is actually injective. It's easier to show this using the contrapositive of the implication in the definition:  $f(n)=f(m) \implies n=m$.

Try writing out $f(n)$ and $f(m)$ as sets and proving the implication above.

---

EDIT: I see in the title you're wondering if it's a bijection. To show the function is not surjective, find a set in $P(\Bbb N)$, a subset of $\Bbb N$, that is not of the form $\{n+1, n+2, \dots\}$.

Comment: How do I prove f(n) and f(m) as sets ?

Comment: You can write them out using the definition of your function: $f(n)=\{n+1,n+2,\dots\}$ and $f(m)=\{m+1,m+2,\dots\}$. Note that you're assuming they are equal and then proving that $m=n$.

Answer (score 0):

I would have put this as a comment but I don't have the reputation. If I understand you correctly, you have a function mapping a set N into its power set. From Cantor's theorem the cardinality of a power set is strictly greater than the original set therefore no bijection exists.

Comment: He seems to actually be asking about injectivity, not bijectivity, but it is good to point out that it can't be a bijection either. Though it is obvious for this particular function.